# Without raising an exception, how do I test for the presence of a JavaScript alert using Capybara and Selenium?

Tags: selenium, capybara

I'm using Capybara and Selenium to drive a Firefox browser for a Cucumber feature I'm writing. (Not a Cucumber question, but as it happens, I'm using Cucumber.) I have a step:

```
Then /^I should see a confirmation of the change$/ do
  expect{page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert}.not_to raise_exception
end
```

<sub>(The real implementation tests for the type of the exception and uses some magic to determine that the confirmation I'm seeing has the correct text. For brevity, that code is excluded.)</sub>

My problem is that to test for the presence of a modal dialog, I possibly have to raise an Exception. Philosophically, this is a problem because this is not exceptional behavior. This is simple stuff.

There is an `#is_alert_present` method in Selenium, but it does not appear that there is any way to access it:

- `page.driver` gives me a [`Capybara::Selenium::Driver`](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/be672f3dcfa9a314188416286edd62a0963e6be9/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb#L11).
- `page.driver.browser` gives me a `Selenium::WebDriver::Driver` (which, in my case, is a Firefox driver).
- Neither of these objects appears to have any access to a `Selenium::Client::Base` which includes the `Selenium::Client::GeneratedDriver` module, which defines [`#is_alert_present`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/Client/GeneratedDriver.html#is_alert_present-instance_method)

Without raising an exception, how do I test for the presence of a JavaScript alert using Capybara and Selenium? Given only a `Selenium::WebDriver::Driver`, is there a way to access a `Selenium::Client:Base`?

Answer (score 0):

hmmm
I would try this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300 /*timeout in seconds*/);
 if(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent())==null)
      return false;
 else
      return true;
```

`ExpectedConditions` is a wrapper class that implements useful conditions defined in `ExpectedCondition`  interface.